# GeoIP - Error: Class 'Database' not found in _registry_check_code()

Tags: 7

On my Drupal 7.78 I installed the GeoIP module https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip
I followed the steps in the Install.txt

```
1. Enable this module as usual.

2. Install one of the Maxmind php API:
   - GeoIP2 [https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php]:
     -- # phar package:
          Download the latest phar package:
          https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php/releases
          Place the file geoip2.phar here:
          sites/all/libraries/GeoIP2-phar/geoip2.phar
    
3. Download one of the GeoLite database files (matching the API):
   - GeoIP2: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/#Downloads
   - Legacy: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/
```

On step 3 I downloaded the file GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb from maxmind.com

```
4. Create the directory 'sites/all/libraries/geoip' and extract the database
   file into this directory.
   You can use other locations too e.g. to share a database with varnish or
   other tools - to do so you can configure the path to the database to use in
   the module configuration (admin/config/system/geoip).
```

After step 4 I get the following error:

```
Warning:  stream_wrapper_register(): class 'TYPO3\PharStreamWrapper\PharStreamWrapper' is undefined in /home/customer/www/mydomain/public_html/misc/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/PharStreamWrapper.php on line 509
    
Error: Class 'Database' not found in _registry_check_code() (line 3503 of /home/customer/www/mydomain/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc
```

Before step 4 there was no error, what am I doing wrong? why do I get this error? how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the registry?

Comment: Thank you Kevin, after rebuilding the registry I get the same warning and the error: Error: Class 'SelectQuery' not found in DatabaseConnection->select() (line 854 of /home/customer/www/mydomain/public_html/includes/database/database.inc

Comment: It seems like there can be some problems with geoip module after SA-CORE-2019-002. Please check these issues on Drupal.org, if one of them would help: [3028265](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3028265) , [3026489](https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip/issues/3026489) , [3026443](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3026443)